# How to sum all the records that get in resultSet in java

Tags: java

Here this code get the quantity for each order . i ant to sum all quantities . and i dont know how to do this .

```
int qt = rs5.getInt("Quantity");


printStr33 = "Committed :";
while (rs5.next()) {
    String xx = InsightUtils.convertMySQLToUSFormat(rs5.getString("OrderDate"));
    String mm = "";
    String yy = "";
    try {
        mm = xx.substring(0, 2);
        yy = xx.substring(8);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    double prce = rs5.getDouble("Price");
    if (prce < lowestPrice) {
        lowestPrice = prce;
    }
    String ordNo = rs5.getString("OrderNo");
    int suppId = rs5.getInt("SupplierId");
    if (suppId == 1 && remarkStr.indexOf("-EE-") == -1) {
        remarkStr += "-EE-";
    }
    if (suppId == 13 && remarkStr.indexOf("-AC-") == -1) {
        remarkStr += "-AC-";
    }
    String supNm = vendorTable.get(suppId + "").substring(0, 3);
    int qt = rs5.getInt("Quantity");


    printStr1 = partNo + ":" + price + " (" + remarks + ")" + " QTY:" + qty + " CST:" + costPrice + " ACT:"
        + actualPrice + " ST:" + units + " RE:" + reorder + " Unit on Order :" + qt  ;
```

Comment: You don't know how to sum up numbers you get in a loop? How about `int sum = 0;` outside the loop and `sum += qt;` inside? - But if that _really_ is your problem then I'd suggest revisiting programming basics before diving deeper into more complex matters. Summing values in a loop is programming 101.

Comment: Do it like  qt = qt + rs5.getInt("Quantity");

Comment: First of all, your code is not representative, because it's not clear how would you want to get the sum. Second, if you only read to sum the quantity, **do not do it**. SQL (which is I assume what it is) supports internal summing of most data types, and is much more performant at doing so.

Answer (score 1):

it could be helpful to you

```
 int sum=0;
 while (rs5.next()) {
       int qt = rs5.getInt("Quantity");  
       sum+=qt;
  }
 out.println(sum);
```